# Check if file is in use before exporting

Tags: loops, powershell

I'm writing a script that will export an excel file to a PDF. I got that part working, However, because I'm saving on top of an existing PDF it cannot be open when the export happens. I'm looking for a way to have PowerShell check if the file is currently open, and if so, wait for X seconds and then check again. If not it can proceed.

It currently works perfectly and breaks if the PDF is open, however I need it to loop.

Here's what I have so far:

```bsh
$path = "c:\users\XXXXX\documents" 
$xlFixedFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type]
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include spreadsheet.xlsx -Recurse 
$File = "c:\users\XXXXX\documents\Exported.pdf"

try {
  [IO.File]::OpenWrite($File).Close();
  $true
} catch {
  break
}

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$objExcel.Visible = $false
foreach ($wb in $excelFiles) {
  $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + ".pdf")
  $workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($wb.FullName, 3)
  $workbook.Saved = $true
  "saving $filepath"
  $workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath)
  $objExcel.Workbooks.Close() 
}
$objExcel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want; thanks to [Ben Baird](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/ben%20%20baird/) for the Test-FileLock function.

```
function Test-FileLock {
    param ([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Path)

    $oFile = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $Path

    if ((Test-Path -Path $Path) -eq $false)
    {
      return $false
    }

    try
    {
        $oStream = $oFile.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, [System.IO.FileShare]::None)
        if ($oStream)
        {
          $oStream.Close()
        }
        # file is unlocked.
        $false
    }
    catch
    {
      # file is locked by a process.
      return $true
    }
}

$path = "c:\users\XXXXX\documents" 
$xlFixedFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type]
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include spreadsheet.xlsx -Recurse 
$File = "c:\users\XXXXX\documents\Exported.pdf"

while((Test-FileLock $file) -eq $true)
{
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$objExcel.Visible = $false
foreach ($wb in $excelFiles) {
  $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + ".pdf")
  $workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($wb.FullName, 3)
  $workbook.Saved = $true
  "saving $filepath"
  $workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath)
  $objExcel.Workbooks.Close() 
}
$objExcel.Quit()
```

The code will check for a file lock and if it is detected wait 3 seconds and then try again. Once the lock is cleared the PDF export code will run.